# Python module providing `word_is_in_language(string word, string ebnf)`

Tags: library, python, language

I have a [EBNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) document, and I want to programmatically determine whether input strings are in the language defined by the EBNF. Are there any python modules that can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The python [TextX](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/textX) module can take a DSL specification and validate against it.